# Access Inner Join to select a record with the Max Date to distinctively select a record from another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using Access and writing a query to join another table which has multiple records with the same ID. So, I only need to fetch the record with the MAX date to fetch only 1 record. I keep getting an syntax error.

Here is my normal Inner Join to the other table:

```
SELECT
table2.NameDesc,
FROM [table1] 
INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  [MyDataTable].[ID], [MyDataTable].[NameDesc], MAX( [MyDataTable].[MyDate]) as RecentDate
            FROM    [MyDataTable]
            GROUP BY  [MyDataTable].[ID]          
        ) table2
ON [table1].[ID] = table2.[ID];
```

Normally on my inner join statement, I write like this:

`INNER JOIN [table3] ON [table1].[ID] = [table3].[ID])`

So I need to fetch only 1 record with the MAX date. I finally was able to
click save but when I click on the DateSheetView, I get the following error:

`"Your query does not include the specified expression "NameDesc" as part of an aggregate function"`

I am new the access query with the [ ] bracket which is different from sql server.

How can I get this Access query to work and fetch the record with the max date from another table?

Any help is appreaciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you use an aggregate function, like MAX, you need to include all other columns you are returning as part of the group by. In order for the query to run without errors, you can do this:

```
    SELECT
    table2.NameDesc
    FROM [table1] 
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  [MyDataTable].[ID], 
                [MyDataTable].[NameDesc], 
                MAX([MyDataTable].[MyDate]) as RecentDate
        FROM    [MyDataTable]
        GROUP BY  [MyDataTable].[ID],
                  [MyDataTable].[NameDesc]           
    ) table2
    ON [table1].[ID] = table2.[ID];
```